# Loop until file LastAccessTime is changed

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a clever way to implement a while loop in C# that loops continously until FileInfo's LastAccessTime is changed.

I'm using a FileSystemWatcher to raise a change event where I do some work on the file, but this one fires as soon as I open the file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the `NotifyFilter` property on the `FileSystemWatcher`. `FileSystemWatcher` does support looking at last access time.

Answer (score 2):

FileSystemWatcher seems like the right way to do this. To only get notifications for LastWrite, set the [`NotifyFilter` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.notifyfilter.aspx) to reflect that:

```
watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
```

Comment: Thanks for your time to reply to my post. I understand the  LastWrite and how to filer out specific file and/or file type. But it seems that with out some timer delay thread sleep process there is no way it to cycle indefinetelly until file is closed. Comming from the "stupid user" perspective the file may be open all day - no telling how long, so I only want to the event to fire when the file is saved/closed. I thought that the filewather's Changed property would do the trick but it turns out that this event is raised as soon as you open the file. Thanks.